# What does the word "trend" as a noun exactly mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Merriam-Webster defines it as:

> 1a: a prevailing tendency or inclination : DRIFT 
> // current trends in education 
> 1b: a general movement : SWING 
> // the trend toward suburban living 
> 1c: a current style or preference : VOGUE 
> // new fashion trends 
> 1d: a line of development : APPROACH 
> // new trends in cancer research

Whereas, Oxford defines it as:

> A general direction in which something is developing or changing. 
> ‘an upward trend in sales and profit margins’

Oxford defines it as a "general direction" of the changes/developments. On the other hand, Merriam-Webster's various definitions of the word does not even connote a direction. Could you also, please, explain the different meanings provided by Merriam-Webster using more simpler usages? Thank you.

Comment: Most currently used  sense is 1c IMO. Note also current usage of “trending” . https://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/trending

Comment: @user121863 What are some non-fashion "trends" in that sense of the word? I'm a new learner, please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: A 'line of development' is a metaphorical directional. A time-line showing increase in infection rate, decrease in weekly sales etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but there is "approach" next to that. Its so confusing.

Comment: 'A general movement' clearly implies direction, and the word *toward* in the associated example makes that even clearer.

Comment: "Approach" can mean either the act of going towards something (a movement), or the particular manner in which you go towards something (a means or procedure); in this case it's referring to the latter.

Comment: @StuartF buy why is it being equated with "a line of development"? A development I think is not always a development in approach.

Comment: @jsw29 which definition of M-W does the Oxford definition correspond to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They’re actually both correct. Oxford refers to a “general direction” of change, but they don’t clarify that direction can be conceptual or metaphorical, not just physical. Merriam-Webster's various definitions are more specific usages but all indicate some sort of direction.

More generally, any information that you could display on a graph *over time* (such as educational methods used, where people live, popularity of fashion styles, or cancer research activity) and the result would show directional movement can be described as a trend.